# How do i generate different and multiple password in c#

Tags: c#

Sorry for my silly question. I am very new to learning c#. Right now i wanted to generate 5 random password for my assigment. After i finish my code, i notice that it generate 5 password but those 5 password are the same. i wanted those password to be different from one another.

Here is my code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int length = 7;
        int i, n = 5;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string pass = CreateRandomPassword(length);
            Console.WriteLine("Password: " + pass);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string CreateRandomPassword(int length)
    {
        string validChars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@$#?%&";
        Random random = new Random();

        char[] chars = new char[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = validChars[random.Next(0, validChars.Length)];
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }

    
}
```

}

The output it produce :
Password: MBZAW09
Password: MBZAW09
Password: MBZAW09
Password: MBZAW09
Password: MBZAW09

i want the output to be like this :
Password: MBZAW09
Password: edr$#c9
Password: 167&uj@
Password: @&dfy71
Password: 1gr6%8u

Can anyone help me out ???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Initialize the `Random` instance outside the `for` loop, not inside your `CreateRandomPassword()` method.

Comment: Use a version of .net that doesn't seed Random from the computer clock, if you're going to make new Randoma in a loop.. but even then..

Comment: i just finish the code. Thanks for the help :) @Progman

Comment: How about calling `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`. There's (IIRC) 122 bits of strong entropy in the version 4 GUIDs it produces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> The Random() constructor uses the default seed value.

This means that the the seed for the Random object is created from the system clock time, which does NOT refresh in milliseconds, but by some larger amount.

Think of the Random object as a list of random numbers, generated based on the seed.

Because you're recreating the Random each call, and the program has a very short running time, you're regenerating the same list over and over again and restarting at the beginning of the list.

Solution:
Create the Random in main, and pass it in as a method parameter.
or,
Make it an static variable, and create it once on start-up and keep reusing it.

Comment: Newsflash: recent versions of net core do not seed from the clock.. not that that makes it reasonable to create a new random on every loop but..

Comment: Thank you for the respond. Right now i am figuring out where should i put my random at. You told me to put it on my main. but i am still confuse on what to change on my code lol.

Comment: @CaiusJard  OP never specified version.

Comment: i just finish the code. Thanks for the help :)